# Regular expression Repetition

Tags: perl

Can someone tell me the regular expression to match the below input:

```
Tom                                                                                                                    
Mary                                
George
```

I think the regular expression is `.*\n.*\n.*\n`, but is there any simpler way to express this?
I tried `[.\*\n]\*` but it does not work.

Comment: are you trying to match 3 consecutive non-empty lines?

Comment: Maybe something like this: ^[A-Za-z]+$

Comment: Often Perl code works by reading files one line at time. You would have to have all three lines in one string for a regular expression to match them. What exactly do you want to do? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to match 3 consecutive non-empty lines. In fact it is a string consists of 3 consecutive non-empty lines

Comment: When asking for help with regex, it helps to 1) explain what is *special* about the text that you wish to match. 2) Provide a couple of clear examples where you *don't want a match*, which are similar to the matching example in some way. For instance it is not clear if you want to allow anythong other than `[A_Z][a-z]+` in each line - would a line `John Doe` still match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$str =~  /(?:.+\n){3}/;
```

Comment: Sorry, Could you tell me what the ":" means in your solution.

Comment: @user3326148: `(?:...)` is a non-capture group. Have a look at: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html Non-capture group is more efficient than a capture group if you don't need to capture ...

Answer (score 0):

Does the following regex work for you? It matches everything except a new line followed by a newline and so on. The last one is optional to account for the last line.

```
[^\n]+[\n][^\n]+\n[^\n]+\n?
```